# missing folder in repository after git add

Tags: git

I'm using folder containing Software Development Kit (SDK), and tried to back it up with git into another folder in my laptop which I use as a git remote.
I used `git add *`.
It seemed that all worked well, I received no error or warning. So then i cloned the remote into another folder, and tried to compile, but got an error saying that files are missing. It turned out that a folder is missing in git.

Any idea what I did wrong ?

```
cd /home/ubuntu/backup
mkdir yamit
cd yamit
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first backup"
git remote add yamit /home/ubuntu/backup/yamit.git
git push -u yamit master
```

Comment: Where was the folder? What was it called? What does `git status` show in each place?

Comment: Hi,
Im using the following sequenct
cd /home/ubuntu/backup
mkdir yamit
cd yamit
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first backup"
git remote add yamit /home/ubuntu/backup/yamit.git
git push -u yamit master

Comment: Folder won't add to track if it empty

Comment: Hi, folder is not empty.

Comment: Is there anyway I can understand what's going wrong ?

Comment: No, I mean the folder that was missing.

Comment: in your sequence there isn't any content at all, so I don't see what folder is missing?

Comment: I've tested the same problematic folder by using git for the folder above it. The same problem occurs. this "include" folder is missing from git. It is not a matter of size, but something else. Any idea ?

Comment: the folder appears in .gitignore. Does anyone have anyidea why it is being ignored ?
#
# Generated files
#
gen_init_cpio
initramfs_data.cpio
initramfs_data.cpio.gz
initramfs_data.cpio.bz2
initramfs_data.cpio.lzma
initramfs_list
include

Comment: if that's snippet from gitignore, then it quite clearly suggests that the folder/files are **autogenerated** -- so,they are automatically built from other files. Someone has noticed that and decided that there's no point in storing them in the repository.If you added something important to that folder, or if you simply don't agree,just remove the line from gitignore, or add a selective `!` directive that will exclude the few important files fro mignoring,  or force-add it.**HOWEVER** the 'include'-type directories arent usually generated.Maybe someone made a mistake. I'd suggest unignoring it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I've resolved this.
Just needed to call add with force into repository.

```
git add * -f
```

Yet, I still don't unedrstand why Git decided to ignore the folder when trying without forcing ( it's non empty folder).

Thanks.
Ran

Comment: Ok, I have completed my answer accordingly.

Comment: VonC answer is more complete.

Answer (score 13):

Whenever you have a missing resource after a git add, you can easily check if it is part of any `.gitignore` with a [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (git 1.8.4+):

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/missing/ressource
```

Simply modify the `.gitignore` by removing its line ignore the resource you need.

Then add and commit again.

If you don't want to modify the `.gitignore` file, then a

```
git add -f .
# or
git add -f path/to/missing/*
```

That can force those ignored resources to be added to the index anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and I see that it is missing:


usr/.gitignore:10:include usr/include/

How should I add it ? It is folder containing other folders which have contents.

Comment: @ransh you can modify this .gitignore to *not* ignore what you want, then add and commit again.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. I wander why git ignore folder with only subdirectories in it (but the subdirectories have contents)

Comment: @ransh yes, ignoring a folder is a shortcut to say "ignore any content within that folder".

Comment: @ransh git itself wouldn't create a `.gitignore`, so I am not sure where that one is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but i ran into this same issue..
Turns out i'd created my current project, and pushed it to a repo after working on it for a few days. Somewhere around that time i must have forgotten to add the missing directory's file to the local directory which is pushed on to my GitHub profile.
Manually adding the file to the directory fixed it for me which is what led me to this conclusion.

Might be another thing to look at that wasn't mentioned earlier!

(mind you I use Intellij, which manages the git system in the background, the CLI approach might not have this same issue).